# How do I order a ManyToManyField in Django and get them out in order?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I've got playlists with many songs in them, and I'd like those songs to stay in order when I get them from a queryset. I've tried the obvious thing - a 'through' model with order_by='song_order' - but that won't work, and trying to make it work with a proxy model on Song (see the code below) ends up throwing this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'
```

Currently, this is what it looks like:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    sid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    artist_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mood = models.ForeignKey('Mood', related_name='songs_with_mood', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.title, self.id)


class PlaylistSong(Song):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        ordering = ['playlist_song_ordering__song_order']
         # ^ this is the line responsible for the Attribute Error

class PlaylistSongs(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey("PlaylistSong", related_name='playlist_song_ordering')
    playlist = models.ForeignKey("Playlist")
    song_order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "api_playlist_songs"
        ordering = ['song_order']

class Playlist(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='owned_playlists')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song', related_name='in_playlists', through='PlaylistSongs')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        unique_together = ("owner", "title", "created",)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that proxy model is supposed to be doing here. The "obvious thing" you mention is the correct answer: you should show exactly why it doesn't work and what happened when you tried.

Comment: Good point. The proxy model's supposed to be giving me a way to sort a queryset of PlaylistSongs by their song_order, which I thought was necessary because I couldn't seem to get `playlist.songs.all()` to be ordered by song_order, and thought ordering by something in a proxy model would be accessible in that way. But I ended up dumping the proxy model and am just making the queryset manually - `playlist.songs.order_by('playlist_song_ordering__song_order')` - which works pretty well. Thanks for pushing me on that!